# Retry user input in Python script

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to "force" a Python script to not "throw me back" into the bash environment if I commit a simple error in my Python script.

Here's an MWE (MWE.py) to illustrate the point:

How can you tell Python NOT to kick me out of the program if I press 3 in the MWE below?

```
x = raw_input("Please input a number 1 or 2: ")
if (x == '1'):
    print '1'
elif (x == '2'):
    print '2'
#else:
    #print 'Neither 1 nor 2.'
```

Notice that my last two lines are commented out.  If I uncomment them, obviously I will get the respective print statement and the program will finish successfully.  However, let's assume that I didn't have those last two lines, and wanted MWE.py to "stay in Python mode" (so to speak) and not harshly return me to the bash shell, thereby forcing me to rerun from scratch with `python MWE.py`.

Is there a way to accomplish this somehow?

Obviously, this is a trivial MWE but I'm trying to understand the principle: is it possible to just return the last prompt that I was presented with right before I committed an input error (such as committed in this MWE when I pressed 3).  Is there basically a "generalized way" to get back to `x = raw_input("Please input a number 1 or 2: ")` (or whatever else was the most recent prompt that I was given before I made an input error)?

This seems particularly important in programs that require multiple user inputs at different stages.  I would hate to start all over.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's called a loop (the parentheses around the conditions are not required):

```
x = None

while x != '1' and x != '2':
    x = raw_input("Please input a number 1 or 2: ")
    if x == '1':
        print '1'
    elif x == '2':
        print '2'
    else:
        print 'Neither 1 nor 2.'

print "all OK"
```

There are many ways of writing this.  You should pay attention to how you initialise `x` before the loop, `None` is typical in python.

Also note the the value of `x` is a string, not an `int`.

This would quickly become unwieldy if you had a large number of possible values to test.  So an alternative approach is to use an *infinite loop* and `break` out on a correct reply:

```
x = None

while True:
    x = raw_input("Please input a number 1 or 2: ")
    if x == '1':
        print '1'
        break
    elif x == '2':
        print '2'
        break
    else:
        print 'Invalid input, try again'

print "all OK"
```

Comment: Figuring out that OP was describing a loop is pretty impressive.

Comment: @cdarke: stupid internet. Nope. The question was tagged `bash` and the answer was a python while loop.

Comment: @cdarke no sarcasm whatsoever.  Very nice didactic example.  Exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann: sorry.  I teach both bash and python, sometimes to new programmers, so the wording of the question and the issue that the OP had was familiar.  Experienced programmers sometimes forget how difficult structures like loops can be when starting out.

Comment: @cdarke I would argue that it's not the loop structure itself we both find impressive, it's the __application__ of it to this bash shell-centric question, where it might have first seemed that the issue to tackle was bash (not the while loop), thereby perhaps requiring extra bash-specific features to the Python code.  Nice application of while loop.

Comment: @warship:  I have to admit that when I saw the title I was considering `exec python myscript.py` to prevent a return to bash.  But full marks to you for a well explained question - makes a nice change from "why doesn't my program work".

Comment: @cdarke Respect.  Please feel free to reword the question as you see fit if you think there may be a better way to point users to the right SO thread. Thank you again.