# Average and Sums Task

Tags: python

Basic task of making code that can find the sum & average of 10 numbers from the user.

My current situation so far:

```py
Sum = 0
print("Please Enter 10 Numbers\n")
for i in range (1,11):
    num = int(input("Number %d =" %i))
sum = Sum + num
avg = Sum / 10
```

However, I want to make it so that if the user inputs an answer such as "Number 2 = 1sd" it doesn't stop the code immediately. Instead I'm looking for it to respond as "Invalid input. Try again" and then it restarts from the failed input.

e.g.

```
"Number 2 = 1sd"
"Invalid input. Try again."
"Number 2 = ..."
```

How would I achieve that?

Comment: You need a nested loop

Comment: `sum = Sum + num` This line needs to be inside the loop, or it will only include the last number into the sum. Also `sum` and `Sum` are different variables, because Python is case sensitive.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retry user input in Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30993853/retry-user-input-in-python-script)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can output an error message and prompt for re-entry of the `i`th number by prompting in a loop which outputs an error message and reprompts on user input error.  This can be done by handling the `ValueError` exception that is raised when the input to the `int()` function is an invalid integer object string initializer such as as `"1sd"`.  That can be done by catching that exception, outputting `Invalid input. Try again.` and continuing when that occurs.

One possible resulting code that may satisfy your requirements is:

```
Sum = 0
print("Please Enter 10 Numbers\n")
for i in range (1,11):
    num = None
    while num is None:
        try:
            num = int(input("Number %d =" %i))
        except ValueError:
            print('Invalid input. Try again.')
sum = Sum + num
avg = Sum / 10
```

Comment: @bamb1 btw it was better to use `.isdigit` instead of `try-except` .

Answer (score 2):

This one is working for me.

```
sum_result = 0
print("Please Enter 10 Numbers\n")
for i in range (1,11):
    try:
        num = int(input("Number %d =" %i))
        sum_result = sum_result + num
    except Exception:
        print("Please try again")
        num = int(input("Number %d =" %i))
        sum_result = sum_result + num
avg_result = sum_result / 10
print(sum_result)
print(avg_result)
```

Suggestions:

1. Check the conventions for name variables in python, you are using builtin functions, which can be an issue in your code.
2. When you are dealing with user inputs, usually you need error handling, so try, except, else, finally, are the way to go.
3. When you have a code similar to this use, you normally name a function to do these tasks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```py
while True:
    try:
        num = int(input('Enter an integer: '))
        break
    except Exception:
        print('Invalid input')
#now num is an integer and we can proceed
```

Answer (score 1):

you can check the input, then continue or return an error, something like this:

```
sum = 0

print('Please Enter 100 Numbers:\n')
for i in range(1, 11):
    num = input('Number %d' % i)
    while not num.isdigit():
        print('Invalid input. Try again.')
        num = input('Number %d' % i)
    sum += int(num)

avg = sum / 10
print('Average is %d' % avg)
```

Comment: Hi Ali, I'm very new to python, can you help me understand why .isdigit is better than using try-except ?

Answer (score 0):

If your data is not too much, I think put them in a list is better. Because you can easier change program to calculate others if you want.

```
nums = [] # a list only store valid numbers
while len(nums) < 10:
  input_n = input("Number %d = " % (len(nums) + 1))
  if input_n.isdigit():
    n = int(input_n)
    nums.append(n)
  else:
    print("Invalid input. Try again.")

# average is more commonly known as a float type. so I use %f.
print("Average = %f" % (sum(nums) / len(nums)))
```

Comment: [Please do not post an answer that consists essentially of
code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer). Please [edit] your
answer to include an explanation of how and why the code solves the problem,
when it should be used, what its limitations are, and if possible a link to
relevant documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
from statistics import mean

i=0

number_list = []

while i <= 9:
    num = input("Please Enter 10 Numbers\n")
    if num.isdigit() ==False:
        print('Invalid input. Try again.')
        num
    else:
        number_list.append(int(num))
        i +=1

print(sum(number_list))
print(mean(number_list))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).